# How do you print Ruby hashes as arrays? I keep getting hex values

Tags: ruby, hash, hex

I am trying to connect to an API and print game information, here is my code.

```
require 'riot_lol_api'

RiotLolApi::TOKEN = 'ive hidden my api key'

client = RiotLolApi::Client.new(:region => 'na')

summoner = client.get_summoner_by_name 'aeipownu'

games = summoner.games.to_a

games.each {|game| print game}

summoner.games.each do |game|
puts
print game
puts
end

summoner.runes.each do |key, value|
print key.to_s
end
```

I'm not sure what I expect to be printed, but all I can get is this.

```
#<RiotLolApi::Model::Game:0x27fc660>
#<RiotLolApi::Model::Game:0x2bf3a58>
#<RiotLolApi::Model::Page:0x2be5fb8>
```

How can the actual data inside of here? I've tried putting it into an array, but I can't seem to print anything useful besides hex.

This is the data I want to get out. https://developer.riotgames.com/api/methods#!/988/3361

I feel like I'm not using the hashes correctly.

If I do

```
summoner = client.get_summoner_by_name 'aeipownu'
#puts summoner.inspect
puts summoner.name
```

I get the result aeipownu

but if I do

```
summoner = client.get_summoner_by_name 'aeipownu'
games = summoner.games()
#puts games.inspect
p games.RawStatsDto.assists
```

It says undefined method 'RawStatsDto' for #
How can I access the game information such as assists?

Comment: What is your expected result?

Comment: Can you post the output of a `p game`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue isn't that you're not using a hash correctly, it's that you are printing out the `Game` object. You may need to make your own method to grab the exact attributes you would like printed. For example

```
def print_assists(game)
  puts game.RawStatsDto.assists
end
```

It is also worth noting that when printing objects for debugging purposes, it is almost always better to use `p` instead of `puts` e.g. `p game`

Comment: I still can't get it to work. It's not recognizing RawStatsDto.assists.

Comment: What does `p game` instead of `puts game` output?

Comment: checkout the edit. p is doing the inpect and that helps because I can see the data inside of the object. As for pulling it out I am having trouble because RawStatsDto isn't a method.

Answer (score 0):

You can convert Hash into array like this..
Ex: 
res = { a: '1', b: '2' }
array = []

res.each do |k,v|
  array << k << v
end

After that, if you type array then it'll show as
[:a,"1",:b,"2"]

Another simple solution:
Array(res).flatten

I hope it will helps.Thanks :)